# problem with upgrading 14.04 to 16.04 computer will not start says " Failed to start Load Kernel Modules

Tags: upgrade

I updated my laptop from 14.04 to 16.04 as invited to do from the update screen.
This update took around 4 hours and when asked to restart laptop the progamme failed with a list of items headed by "Failed to start Load Kernel Modules".

I cannot get out of this state, what do I do?????

Answer (score 0):

Turn off secure boot in your BIOS.

Comment: Enter your computer's BIOS by entering (typically) the F2, DEL, or ESC key when your computer's welcome logo appears at cold boot. Usually it'll tell you what key to use briefly when you turn on your computer from a cold start. Once in the BIOS, look for secure boot, and turn it off.

Comment: Tried this it does'nt work still says Failed to start Load Kernel Modules

Comment: Are you sure that you disabled secure boot? Cold boot once more and see if it works. In terminal, type DKMS STATUS, and copy the results here.

Comment: reboot did not work, I cannot enter any script direct in terminal.

Comment: I can only enter data instructions. To transmit these comments I am using another computer that does not use Ubuntu

Comment: Please describe exactly what you have/see on your screen after trying to boot. Do you see a black and white console mode, where it asks you to login? Can you boot into rescue mode from the GRUB menu?

Comment: I see a list of statements starting with Failed to start. I can get a rescue mode

Comment: Enter recovery mode. Choose root. At the prompt, type: fsck -f / and let it check your filesystem. Then reboot info recovery mode again, and this time choose dpkg and see if it finishes any incomplete installs.

Comment: Followed instructions no change in status

Comment: At the GRUB menu, choose the prior kernel to see if you can boot back into 14.04, and from there, try and do the upgrade again. Please advise.